# Where does windows store what was last used on the run command (Win + R) between reboots?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reboot

Part of my job is to image laptops, and between reboots the last command I gave windows via run (Win + R) is always there. Does anyone know where that information is kept?

It's mostly idle curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`